# How the legends on Google charts can be wrapped

Tags: charts

I need the legends of Google chart to get wrapped (comes in new line) automatically if it exceeds container area.
I don't want scroll button as it is not enough convenient. 
With available customization options, seems it cannot be done. 
Any other way?

Answer (score 25):

Use the maxLines property for the legend.
i.e.:

```
options.legend = {position: 'top', maxLines: 5};
```

Note that this undocumented property only works if the legend is positioned at the top and there is enough vertical space to render both the chart and multi-line legend.

Comment: legend:{ position: 'bottom', maxLines: 5 },


This does not change how it is displayed unfortunately.

Comment: See my answer: "Note that this undocumented property only works if the legend is positioned at the top..."

Answer (score 0):

with the maxLines property for the legends, chartArea with specific set of values can help in rendering the display.

```
legend: { position: "top", alignment: "start", maxLines: 2 },
chartArea: {top:50,bottom:30,right:0,left:50, 'width': '100%' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of testing of this and it seems that you need to have chartArea width and height set to 'auto'. Still not perfect but sort of OK.